# i want same foreground colour on button which is given by command choose_me

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser


def choose_me():
    s=colorchooser.askcolor(title="select colour")
    root.config(background=s[1])
    print(s)

root =Tk()


button= Button(root,text="choose colour",command=choose_me).pack()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.mainloop()
#i need to change the foreground colour of button same as the root window ...i need some help to overcome this problem ...
```

> i need some help 
>       #i need to change the foreground colour of button same as the root window ...i need some help to overcome this problem ...

Comment: What's stopping you from achieving your goal? The methods to do this are all documented. Have you tried changing the color?

Answer (score 0):

Use `button.config` to change the `foreground` inside the `callback` function to the same color as the `background` of the master window chosen from the `colorchooser`

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

button = Button(root,text="choose colour")
button.pack()

def choose_me():
    s=colorchooser.askcolor(title="select colour")
    root.config(background=s[1])
    # assign the same color as foreground to the button
    button.config(fg=s[1])

button.config(command=choose_me)

root.mainloop()
```

**Screenshot**

`Red` background of root window with `Red` foreground of `Button`.

[image: bgfg]

Hope this helps you.